# I want to implement scroll pagination in my chat application

Tags: node.js, reactjs, react-native

So recently I working on chat application and I found out that message list API required pagination. so I found out some library and custom scroll pagination but did't work for me, they are only targeting main scrollbar in the project. also they only working in downwards in scrollbar

I want to target message list scrollbar and when user scroll upwards then API should be called for next data. please help me out. Thanks in advance

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.